# Retrieving selenium logs and screenshots from grid back in Intern

Tags: json, selenium, intern

There are two parts to my question in regards to Intern workflow in case of exception:

1- Per Selenium [Desired Capabilities](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#specific) specifications,  RemoteWebDriver captures screentshots on exceptions by default (unless it is disabled by setting webdriever.remote.quiteExceptions.)  Is it possible to retrieve these screenshots in Intern?

2- I have set up a Selenium Grid with multiple platforms/browsers and can execute Intern tests on the grid successfully.  However I am trying to gather the logs back in my Intern environment so that I don’t have to sign on to each machine on the grid to see the logs.  I am particularly interested in server, driver, and browser logs based upon selenium [logging](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Logging) guide.  I tried adding the following Intern configurations using the Selenium Desired Capabilities guide but wasn't able to get any logs:

```
capabilities: {
'selenium-version': '2.39.0',
'driver': 'ALL',
'webdriver.log.driver':'INFO',
'webdriver.chrome.logfile': 'C:\\intern\\logs \\chromedriver.log',
'webdriver.firefox.logfile':'C:\\intern \\logs\\firefox.log'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a screenshot yourself you can call `remote.takeScreenshot().then(function (base64Png) {})`, but there is no way that I am aware of to retrieve the automatically generated screenshots—there appears to be nothing in the [WebDriver JsonWireProtocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) to do so.

To retrieve logs, you can call `remote.log(typeOfLog).then(function (logs) {})`. See the [JsonWireProtocol on log](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#POST_/session/%3asessionId/log) for more information on what you get back.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Could you also give an example of the callback function when I need to save the image or log in my project workspace?

Comment: Also, as for the log types, do the vary from one webdriver to another?  an example for that would be nice too! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to capture automatically generated screenshots. Using a custom reporter (https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-and-Writing-Reporters#custom-reporters) I was able to save a screen shot and log browser console logs into a file.

As mentioned in the link above, when the '/test/fail' topic callback is called, it passes in a test object. If the webdriver had failed internally, this object will have a 'test.error.cause.value.screen' variable present in it. This is the variable that stores the webdriver generated screenshot. So the following is what I did:

```
if (test.error.cause.value.screen) {
    //Store this variable into a file using node's fs library
}
```

If you look at the error object, you will also get to see more error information that the webdriver has logged.

Regarding the browser logs, @C Snover has hit the nail on that one. But that information is only available inside the remote object. This object is available when the '/session/start' topic callback is called. So what I did is I created a map that mapped the session ID from the remote object to the remote object itself. And luckily, the test object has the session ID in it too. So, I retrieved the remote object from my map using test.sessionId as the key to the map and logged the browser logs too. So in short this is what I did:

```
'/session/start': function (remote) {
    sessions[remote.sessionId] = { remote: remote };
},

'/test/fail': function (test) {
    var remote = sessions[test.sessionId].remote;
    remote._wd.log('browser', function (err, logs) {
        //Store the logs array into a file using node's fs library
    });
}
```